# Not able to integrate netbanking and other payment options in payumoney

Tags: payumoney

I want to integrate the payumoney redirect URL when netbanking is selected or debit card is selected.I have implemented the credit card payment which was in the integration kit and it is working fine.But I cannot find options for debit card,netbanking and other options,Please guide me.

I have implemented the below using java.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using it in Test mode?

If yes, PayUMoney does not have payment options for sandbox so you can only use the card option using the test card credentials given on the website. If you want to check transactions with other options you need to check those in Live Mode only. Note that in live mode you'll be having all the payment options. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the JAVA Project supplied from Payumoney and I could get the other options like netbanking,debit card and UPI